# KendoUI Grid binding remote data to showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendoUI grid on the *.cshtml page. I'm trying to implement server side paging to the grid. It will only return 10 records at a time, as that is the page size, and a count of all the active records to determine the number of pages needed. The data is being returned from the method but not displaying on the front end. Please see below,

[image: It shows the total number of pages passed through but not the data]

Data is being passed front end when I look at the passed JSONResult,

[image: Passed Data from the JSONResult]

*.cshtml -

```
@(Html.Kendo()
        .Grid<Reckon.Service.Payroll.Data.DTO.EmployeeDto>()
        .Name("EmployeeGrid")
        .Columns(cols =>
        {
            cols.Bound(emp => emp.Id).Title("ID").Hidden();
            cols.Bound(emp => emp.EmployeeNumber).Title("Employee ID").Width(100);
            cols.Bound(emp => emp.IsPayRunReady).Title("Status").Width(10).ClientTemplate("<span title='This employee is #= IsPayRunReady ? '': 'not '#payrun ready.' class='#= IsPayRunReady ? 'okICN-small' : 'alertICN-small'#'>#= IsPayRunReady ? '': 'Not' # #= IsPayRunReady ? 'P':'p'#ayrun ready</span>");
            cols.Bound(emp => emp.FirstName).Title("First Name").Width(100);
            cols.Bound(emp => emp.LastName).Title("Last Name").Width(100);
            cols.Bound(emp => emp.DateOfBirth).Title("DOB").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Width(100);
            cols.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("EmployeeDetailEdit", "EmployeeDetail") + "/#=Id#'>Edit</a>").Width(50);
            cols.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("EmployeeDetailRead", "EmployeeDetailRead") + "/#=Id#'>View</a>").Width(50);
            cols.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a class='k-button xxx' tag='#=Id#'>Delete</a>").Width(50);
        })
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable.ButtonCount(5))
        .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
        .Filterable()
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
        .Navigatable()            
        //.Events(evt => evt.DataBound("afterGridLoaded"))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .PageSize(10)
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Model(model => { model.Id(emp => emp.Id); })
            .Read(read => read.Action("EmployeeListPerPage", "EmployeeDetail"))
    )
)
```

Controller.cs -

```
public ActionResult EmployeeListPerPage([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        Dispose();
        EmployeeListRequest empList = new EmployeeListRequest();
        empList.PageNum = request.Page;
        empList.PageSize = request.PageSize;

        var dataSource = _payrollService.GetEmployeeListPerPage(empList);
        var model = new EmployeeListModel(dataSource);
        return Json(new
        {
            Data = model.Employees.ToDataSourceResult(request),
            Total = dataSource.Total
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        //return Json(model.Employees.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This will gives me the option to set the number of pages but the data is not being display on the page. When I used the ***return JSON*** at the bottom which is commented out, it will display the data on the grid but then will only show one page. Please see below,

[image: Only showing one page]

Any help would to correct this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your returned JSON in the screenshot has incorrectly nested fields:

```
{
  Data: {
    Data: [],
    Errors: ,
    Total: 10
  },
  Total: 10001
}
```

The DataSource is looking for your data in the `Data` property, but the array is actually in `Data.Data` so no data is being displayed.

The line that is commented out *looks* like it should be correct, but it looks like it is returning a `Total` of only 10. That is the reason only 1 page is displayed when you use that code, I can't tell from the code you have posted why `.ToDataSourceResult()` would not find the correct total.

Can you do this instead?

```
var dataSourceResult = model.Employees.ToDataSourceResult(request); // let Kendo build the data
dataSourceResult.Total = dataSource.Total; // replace total with your own count.
return Json(dataSourceResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); // return as JSON
```

Comment: I tried to the method as you mentioned above but it gives me an error and says that _**it does not contain a definition for Total**_. The only options in the DataSourceRequest are as following `IList<Kendo.Mvc.AggregateDescriptor> Aggregates, IList<Kendo.Mvc.IFilterDescriptor> Filters,  IList<Kendo.Mvc.GroupDescriptor> Groups, int Page, int PageSize,  IList<Kendo.Mvc.SortDescriptor> Sorts`. Could this be a version issue with the kendo dll that I'm current using? ** Assembly Kendo.Mvc.dll, v2013.2.918.340**

Comment: Hi @CodingWithSpike, my bad. That works correctly. Need a caffeine refuel. Thanks for the help.